# How to Merge Docker Compose file with Bash

Tags: bash, shell, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to merge the docker-compose.yml file with the docker-compose2.yml file with bash.

**docker-compose.yml :**

```
version: "3"

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
      - "/opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

**docker-compose2.yml :**

```
version: "3"

services:
  nexus2:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
      - "/opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"

volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

**Output I Want:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
      - "/opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

  nexus2:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
      - "/opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

How do I get this output with bash?

Answer (score 41):

The Docker Compose [config command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/) does exactly what you need, it takes multiple compose file and merges them.

Just pass them using multiple `-f` flags:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose2.yml config
```

or using an environment variable:

```
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:docker-compose2.yml docker-compose config
```

---

The same approach is valid for every Docker Compose command, so if your final target is, for example, to set up your project, you can directly run:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose2.yml up
```

Check the documentation for further details on [how to specify multiple compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/#specifying-multiple-compose-files).

Comment: The way of having the COMPOSE_FILE environment variable set is really smart. Especially when having multiple docker-compose commands in a Jenkinsfile. Thanks for that solution.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do this (easily as a one-liner) in native bash without writing a script. I was curious so I did a quick search and found a yaml manipulation tool which supports merging yaml (docker-compose) files and looks like it fits your use-case.

I used `brew` to install on MacOS but there are instructions for Linux as well - https://mikefarah.github.io/yq/.

```
brew install yq
```

Showing existing files:

```
$ cat file1.yaml
version: "3"

services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
      - "/opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

volumes:
  nexus-data: {}

$ cat file2.yaml
version: "3"

services:
  nexus2:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    volumes:
      - "/opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data"
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"

volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

Merge both files outputting to stdout:

```
$ yq m file1.yaml file2.yaml
services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    volumes:
    - /opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data
  nexus2:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    ports:
    - 8082:8082
    volumes:
    - /opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data
version: "3"
volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

There may be a native way but I just redirected the stdout to a file:

```
$ yq m file1.yaml file2.yaml > file3.yaml
$ cat file3.yaml
services:
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    ports:
    - 8081:8081
    volumes:
    - /opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data
  nexus2:
    image: sonatype/nexus3
    ports:
    - 8082:8082
    volumes:
    - /opt/nexus3/nexus-data:/nexus-data
version: "3"
volumes:
  nexus-data: {}
```

There are a lot of examples in their documentation for you to explore - https://mikefarah.github.io/yq/merge/.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new way to do it, you can use `docker compose convert` here is example fit to what you're trying to do:

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose2.yml convert > output.yml
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/)

Comment: Convert is an alias of config, which has already been provided as an answer. https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/main/cmd/compose/config.go#L67